# Copy all Attributes [Not only values of attributes but whole list of attributes] of an element

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-1.0

I have a scenario where i want to copy all the attributes including namespaces [Here I mean the entire attribute list and namespace list and not just the values of the attributes] from an XML tag in the input XML.

**For Ex:**

**Input XML:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<enricher>
    <result>
        <xbrl xmlns="http://www.xbrl.org/2003/instance" 
        xmlns:idp-com="http://www.dnb.com/IDP/Common/Vers1" 
        xmlns:idp-enumcom="http://www.dnb.com/IDP/Common/Enumeration/Common/Vers1" 
        xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.dnb.com/IDP/Product/Common/Vers1 ../Common/ProductCommonTaxonomy.xsd 
        http://www.dnb.com/IDP/Common/Vers1 ../../Data/Common/CommonTaxonomy.xsd">
            <context id="defaultI">
                <entity>
                    <identifier scheme="http://www.dnb.com">Text</identifier>
                </entity>
                <period>
                    <instant>2000-07-14</instant>
                </period>
            </context>
        </xbrl>
    </result>
</enricher>
```

**Output XML:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<enricher>
    <result>
        <xbrlresp xmlns="http://www.xbrl.org/2003/instance" 
        xmlns:idp-com="http://www.dnb.com/IDP/Common/Vers1" 
        xmlns:idp-enumcom="http://www.dnb.com/IDP/Common/Enumeration/Common/Vers1" 
        xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.dnb.com/IDP/Product/Common/Vers1 ../Common/ProductCommonTaxonomy.xsd 
        http://www.dnb.com/IDP/Common/Vers1 ../../Data/Common/CommonTaxonomy.xsd">
            <context id="defaultI">
                <entity>
                    <identifier scheme="http://www.dnb.com">Text</identifier>
                </entity>
                <period>
                    <instant>2000-07-14</instant>
                </period>
            </context>
        </xbrlresp>
    </result>
</enricher>
```

The output should have the `<xbrlresp>` tag with all the namespaces and attributes of the `<xbrl>`.

Comment: Hi, why change the namespace URIs of this 7-year old question? I rolled back your edits (and rejected the changes to my answer) - because you do not give any explanation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**EDIT**: After you have revealed the *actual* problem, I have also changed the stylesheet. Again, your input is not well-formed XML because a namespace is not defined:

```
`xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
```

**XML Input**

```
<enricher>
    <result>
        <xbrl xmlns="http://www.xbrl.org/2003/instance"
        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xmlns:idp-com="http://www.dnb.com/IDP/Common/Vers1" 
        xmlns:idp-enumcom="http://www.dnb.com/IDP/Common/Enumeration/Common/Vers1" 
        xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.dnb.com/IDP/Product/Common/Vers1 ../Common/ProductCommonTaxonomy.xsd 
        http://www.dnb.com/IDP/Common/Vers1 ../../Data/Common/CommonTaxonomy.xsd">
            <context id="defaultI">
                <entity>
                    <identifier scheme="http://www.dnb.com">Text</identifier>
                </entity>
                <period>
                    <instant>2000-07-14</instant>
                </period>
            </context>
        </xbrl>
    </result>
</enricher>
```

**XSLT Stylesheet**

The stylesheet is a simple identity transformation with an exception, namely replacing the `xbrl` element with a new one.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:transform xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0"
    xmlns:xb="http://www.xbrl.org/2003/instance">

    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>
    <xsl:output method="xml" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes" />

    <xsl:template match="xb:xbrl">
      <xsl:element name="xbrlresp" namespace="http://www.xbrl.org/2003/instance">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
      </xsl:element>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:transform>
```

**XML Output**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<enricher>
   <result>
      <xbrlresp xmlns="http://www.xbrl.org/2003/instance" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.dnb.com/IDP/Product/Common/Vers1 ../Common/ProductCommonTaxonomy.xsd          http://www.dnb.com/IDP/Common/Vers1 ../../Data/Common/CommonTaxonomy.xsd">
         <context xmlns="http://www.xbrl.org/2003/instance" xmlns:idp-com="http://www.dnb.com/IDP/Common/Vers1" xmlns:idp-enumcom="http://www.dnb.com/IDP/Common/Enumeration/Common/Vers1" id="defaultI">
            <entity>
               <identifier scheme="http://www.dnb.com">Text</identifier>
            </entity>
            <period>
               <instant>2000-07-14</instant>
            </period>
         </context>
      </xbrlresp>
   </result>
</enricher>
```

Comment: @AkhilJacobJohn Hi,edited too - this is the actual answer. _All_ Namespaces are copied when using my code. A namespace is not an attribute, by the way.

Comment: @AkhilJacobJohn P.S. On Stackoverflow, it is considered good manners to _accept_ answers that were helpful to you. So, please accept an answer to [your last question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25342428/need-xsl-code-to-achieve-this) - this one, too if it solved your problem.

Comment: @AkhilJacobJohn Please see Ian's answer on how to keep all the namespaces together. I do not think I need to edit my post and repeat it there.

Comment: @AkhilJacobJohn Please avoid adding ever more comments to ask new questions. We have provided ample advice for now. I suggest you take a few minutes to think about your issues _on your own_ and ask a clean, **new** question if you have other problems.

Answer (score 1):

Extending [the answer from Matthias](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25359637/592139), if, for aesthetic reasons, you want to copy the namespace declarations of the `xbrl` element onto the new element you're creating, you can do this using

```
<xsl:template match="xb:xbrl">
  <xsl:element name="xbrlresp" namespace="http://www.xbrl.org/2003/instance">
    <xsl:copy-of select="namespace::*" />
    <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
  </xsl:element>
</xsl:template>
```

The `copy-of` copies the *namespace nodes* from the input `xbrl` element onto the generated `xbrlresp`, which should result in the serializer adding the namespace declarations.

Comment: @AkhilJacobJohn Have you corrected your input XML as suggested by Matthias to declare the `xsi` namespace prefix?  I suspect things will get confused if your input is not namespace-well-formed.

Comment: @AkhilJacobJohn then the `@*` in the `apply-templates` should capture the attribute, and the `match="@*|node()"` identity template will copy it.  Do you have any other templates that might be matching the `xsi:schemaLocation` attribute node and getting in the way?

Comment: @AkhilJacobJohn The `xsi:schemaLocation` is definitely [there](http://xsltransform.net/bFDb2BQ). And since I am writing anyway, let me remind you that you have still not accepted an answer to your last question!